# SQL Server : pattern to include parenthesis and exclude all other characters

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pattern-matching

I am performing pattern matching on `@ProductDescription_Glossary` in SQL Server 2005 to replace complete words.

`@GlossaryKeyword` variable contains word to be matched and replaced.

The following code replaces `@GlossaryKeyword` found at the beginning, at the end and in the end of `@ProductDescription_Glossary`, but this code cannot handle replacement successfully if  `@ProductDescription_Glossary` contains parentheses at start or end of word

Case 1: this case is working properly - Heather is not replaced with tooltip link with word Heatherd

```
@GlossaryKeyword = Heather
@ProductDescription_Glossary = Heathered
```

Case 2: this case fails - In this case Heather is replaced, my requirement is that, heather do not get replaced, as in case 1 so provide me with required pattern.

```
@GlossaryKeyword = Heather
@ProductDescription_Glossary = (Heathered
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: `@GlossaryKeyword` has alpha numeric, hyphen and / character only i,e (0-9, A-Z, a-z, -, /)

`@ProductDescription_Glossary` contains HTML tags, which are handled by default (may be due to collation settings on my server)

Code:

```
if PATINDEX ('%[^a-z]' +  @GlossaryKeyword  + '[^a-z]%','.' + @ProductDescription_Glossary    + '.') > 0  

BEGIN   

    SET @ProductDescription_Glossary = REPLACE(@ProductDescription_Glossary,@GlossaryKeyword,  '<a target="_blank" id="q_' + CAST (@GlossaryID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '" class="anchor_regular_Mehroon" href="javascript: void(0);">' + @GlossaryKeyword + '</a>')       
    SET @GlossaryToolTip = @GlossaryToolTip + '<div id="a_q_' + CAST (@GlossaryID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '"  class="toolTip_glossary" style="display:none;">' + @GlossaryKeywordDescription + '</div>'
END
```

Comment: First of all, `PATINDEX()` does not support RegEx - it only does wildcard matching. Second: I added variable definitions, executed, and it works as expected..

Comment: @marc_s , i want that (Heathered do not get replaced when there is following scenario.

SET ProductDescription_Glossary = ', poly (Heathered red, purple, royal and navy)' ;
SET GlossaryKeyword = 'Heather'

Answer (score 0):

Just as ( ) to the not

```
select PATINDEX('%[^a-z(]'+ 'Heather' + '[^a-z)]%', '(Heathered red, purple, royal and navy)')
```

And it is not regex.
And you want to exclude ( - not include.

Comment: no this is not helpful .
I want to exclude parenthesis from pattern matching

scenario. SET ProductDescription_Glossary = ', poly (Heather red, purple, royal and navy)' ; SET GlossaryKeyword = 'Heather'
Then heather must be replaced

Comment: why you have down voted this question ? were you feeling sleepy while reading my previous comment ? then take a good nap before coming to Stack Over Flow.
See the If condition in my question, I have to replace plain text  in ProductDescription_Glossary with href tag to display tooltip when mouse is hovered on this text ..

(heather) will be replaced to 

(<a target="_blank" id="q_336" class="anchor_regular_Mehroon" href="javascript: void(0);">Heather</a>)

Comment: @ShujaatKagathra Take dose of reality.  Heather to Heather is no change.  "Do not get replaced" is not English.  Patindex is not regex.

Comment: @balm 1. I am not changing Heather to Heather, I have to replace Heather with an anchor tag, 2. I like to speak English but I am not as much good as English is not my native language, 3. My question starts with "I am performing pattern matching on...."  and reason for placing my question here is that i do not know much about PatIndex .

Comment: @balm See Description of product on these Pages

[District DT6000p](http://204.12.49.76:8001/district/dt6000p-young-mens-very-important-tee-with-pocket.htm) ,
[Gildan g500B](http://204.12.49.76:8001/gildan/g500b-youth-53-oz-heavy-cotton-t-shirt.htm)

Comment: @Balm, dude so what you expect from me after down voting my question without understanding it !